# How can I use find() or filter() using Play-Morphia on a hash-map object?

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I'm using Play framework and Play-Morphia for using MongoDb in Java.
I got an entity Message which defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Message{
    public String senderId;
    public Date date;
    public String initiatorId;
    @Embedded public MessageBasicInfo basicInfo;
}
```

The MessageBasicInfo defined as follows:

```
public class MessageBasicInfo implements IModel{
    public HashMap<String, Boolean> recipients;
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve from Mongo only the messages which their value in recipients' hashmap is true.
I know how to do it in list for example but no idea how to do it with a hashmap object.
I'll appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: In short you want to get `key` on the basis of `value` . For this you will have to iterate through whole `HashMap` and check for the `value` to be `true` , if it is then save the corresponding `key` in `List<String>` object.

Comment: yes but for what you just suggested I don't use the advantages that MongoDB gives us. I know there's a way to query Mongo for all the Messages which their recipients' value is true or false, I just don't know how to do it on hash-map...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashMap is very hard to query. I recommend you re-organize your `MessageBasicInfo` as

```
public class MessageBasicInfo implements IModel {
   public String key;
   public Boolean value;
}
```

And then you can query for all `true` value messages via:

```
Message.q("basicInfo.value", true).asList();
```

Comment: well, I've already considered that as an option, but I think it won't heart to know once and for all how to query it hash-map...